# Transform Image to four projected points in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have four points and I would like to draw an `UIImageView` with corners in those four points. 
The four points represent an arbitrary rectangle (might be a trapez or a parallelogram).

I guess I somehow need to make a transform from those four points, but I'm not quite sure how.

Any suggestions?

Other solutions?

Comment: try using Bezier path

Comment: Do you want it in a way that you have a image and you want to present the image within the 4 specified points?

Comment: @OmkarGuhilot I want to project the image onto a "surface" defined by four points

Answer (score -1):

Look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169176/2d-transformation-matrix-to-make-a-trapezoid-out-of-a-rectangle to determine your transformation matrix.

Note that you cannot use a 2D matrix so you have to use a `CATransform3D`.

```
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
// update transform elements, .m11, .m12, .m13, etc.
imageView.layer.transform = transform;
```

Comment: yeah, The question was actually about how to create this matrix in Swift :-)

Comment: Okay than remove the `;`s. You can still access the transformation matrix elements with `.m11`, `.m12`, etc for each row / column (except for the last row IIRC).

Comment: Tim, The question is how to CREATE THE MATRIX needed for the transform, in swift. Not how to apply it.
Basically this line in your answer
// update transform elements, .m11, .m12, .m13, etc.

Comment: Look at the second answer I referred. You start with 3 of your 4 points (u, v and w) subtract the fourth and put each coordinate in the first two rows of the matrix. As for the rest of the matrix, the identity elements will suffice. Lastly translate to the fourth point.